# Haskell Parsing Error on 'let'

Tags: haskell

Hey I'm having an issue with parsing errors and I am pretty new to this. I couldn't find much on white space rules of Haskell when it comes to do's and let's. If you could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

CODE:

```
import Data.Char

-- shorterThan function takes a filename and a length and returns all words in the file shorter than the given length.

shorterThan :: String -> Int -> IO [String]
shorterThan fileName len = do fileContents <- readFile fileName
                                let fileWords = lines fileContents
                                let shorterThanWords = [word | word <- fileWords, (length word) < len]
                                return shorterThanWords

shorterThan' :: String -> Int -> IO [String]
shorterThan' fileName len = readFile fileName >>= (\fileContents -> let fileWords = lines fileContents
                                                                        shorterThanWords = [word | word <-fileWords, (length word) < len]
                                                                    in return shorterThanWords))
```

Comment: Looking at the source of your question, it seems you're mixing tabs & spaces. Haskell doesn't really like that (something may look like it's aligned in your editor but not be considered as such by the compiler because they don't consider tabs as wide as you do). It is generally recommended to stick to spaces only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your do-block is not properly indented. Here's one way:

```
shorterThan :: String -> Int -> IO [String]
shorterThan fileName len = do
  fileContents <- readFile fileName
  let fileWords = lines fileContents
  let shorterThanWords = [word | word <- fileWords, length word < len]
  return shorterThanWords
```

The `let` must begin at the start of the do-block indentation.

You also have one `)` too many at the end, it seems.

I'd prefer to separate the "shorter than" logic into a non-I/O function like so:

```
shorterThan :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
shorterThan n ws = [ w | w <- ws, length w < n ]

wordsFromFile :: FilePath -> IO [String]
wordsFromFile filePath = words <$> readFile filePath

main :: IO ()
main = wordsFromFile "hello.txt" >>= mapM_ putStrLn . shorterThan 5
```

This makes it more reusable and more easily testable.